# THREE.Raycaster not working properly with scaled THREE.Sprite

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use THREE.Raycaster to show an html label when the user hover an object. It works fine if I use THREE.Mesh but with THREE.Sprite it looks like that there is a space that increases with the scale of the object.

The creation process is the same for both scenario, I only change the type based on **USE_SPRITE** variable.

```
if ( USE_SPRITE ) {

  // using SpriteMaterial / Sprite
  m = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
  o = new THREE.Sprite( m );

} else {

  // using MeshBasicMaterial / Material
  m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
  o = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ),  m );

}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/J0HHFMpDB5INYLSCTWHG?p=preview

I am not sure if it is a bug with THREE.Sprite or if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance.

three.js r73

Comment: Tip: there is no need to scale the z-component of your sprite. `sprite.scale.set( s, s, 1 )`. Same for your plane.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I updated the demo =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this a bug in three.js r.75.

Raycasting with meshes in three.js is exact. However, with sprites, it is an approximation.

Sprites always face the camera, can have different x-scale and y-scale applied (be non-square), and can be rotated (`sprite.material.rotation = Math.random()`).

In `THREE.Sprite.prototype.raycast()`, make this change:

```
var guessSizeSq = this.scale.x * this.scale.y / 4;
```

That should work much better for square sprites. The corners of the sprite will be missed, as the sprite is treated as a disk.

three.js r.75

Comment: Perfect!!! I spent hours trying to figure it out and you did in minutes. Thank you.

Comment: This change has been [implemented](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/8424) in r.76dev.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley I also used on a project with r75 and it worked like a charm.