# Threejs Raycasting a Sprite-Canvas Object is inaccurate

Tags: three.js

I'm new to threejs, so I hope this makes sense.

I'm placing a Sprite Object into my scene with a canvas (text) texture.  I'm able to do this with no problem.  Once I try to determine if I've clicked on this Sprite it seems inaccurate.  If the mouse is above it, it seems that the raycaster finds it as a intersecting object.  Is there something special that needs to be done when raycasting a canvas texture on a Sprite?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36123458/three-raycaster-not-working-properly-with-scaled-three-sprite

Comment: Thanks WestLangely.  That describes my problem.