# How to make a rounded corner 2d Sprite with plane geometry shader always facing the camera in threejs webgl geometry space

Tags: three.js

How can I draw a rectangle texture as a 2d sprite with rounded corners, like this:

```
   _____
  /     \
  |     |
  \_____/
```

I figured, i need to use a mask texture and a shader to make a circle mask but I can't apply shadermaterial to a 2d sprite!

Comment: rounded corner cube: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_subdivision.html then facing the camera: mesh.lookAt( camera.position );

Comment: @Radio this sprite moves in 3d world, and it gets smaller because of the perspective, I want it to look as in orthogonal projection and stay the same like an hud element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a texture with [drawing on a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40543416/4045502) or draw a texture you want in any image editor, then apply it to a sprite. If you want the sprite to have the same size, independent on distance, then look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40452050/4045502). Both my answers have jsfiddle examples.

Comment: why do i use threejs if i am gonna draw on canvas?, just make it part of the library it lacks extensive documentation anyway

Comment: Maybe this [shadertoy example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tlSzr) will give you an idea to achieve what you want. But totally IMHO, the less computations (and on a GPU too), the better.